# Applying ad-hoc SQL queries that handle millions of records without any pagination

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am working on a project to build an IDE like SQL Developer (or SQL Server Management Studio). I am intending to write any ad-hoc queries in the IDE editor and show the retrieved data in a datagrid. The project is built in C# for a .NET Windows Form environment.

My challenge is to execute any select operations on the large tables (millions of rows) without applying any pagination. Pagination will change my actual query in SQL Server Profiler.

Suppose, if I write

```
SELECT * 
FROM LargeTableA
```

and apply virtualization and each time I fetch 50 rows from `LargeTableA`, internally the actual query will be changed and the number of database hits will be multiple. This is not my expectation.

I want to accomplish the job like Professional SQL IDEs (SQL Developer). I need to know how they do it without applying pagination. I am kindly requesting experts suggestions to guide me so that I can accomplish the task with your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Do we agree about the basics? When you call command.ExecuteReader() you get a SqlDataReader. This has a Read() method that lets you iterate, once, forward, through your result set. Your connection stays open until you close it. You can close it before you've read every row if, for whatever reason, you decide you don't need to continue. You don't know, and shouldn't care, how many rows are buffered in your connection. All this is independent of pagination in the sql query, and it would let you, for example, implement an infinite scroll in your data grid, or display the first n records only, to avoid burying your application. Does that help?